# How to have simple model class names in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework

I would like, for my model classes, that instead of having to name them "Default_Model_Class1", they would be simply named "Class1".

I can't find a way to do that.
Thanks

Comment: Another question is: Why do you want that? There are good reasons, why its not used. First you may get into trouble because of classname conflicts. Then the Prefix is also some kind of namespace (PHP<5.3 do not support native namespaces), which get lost, if you remove it. So instead of saying "The Object is a 'Class1' (whatever this means) and is a Model and is from Default-Module" you just want to say "The Object is a 'Class1'"?

Comment: This is a simple small website, I want it easy to develop. And furthermore I want to use that without having by class/function names: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer? By Cheating.

If you have all your models in, let's say, application/models, you can add that path to your include path and set Zend's autoloader to fallback when it cannot find based on good naming practices (see KingCrunch's comment)

To tell the autoloader to fallback:

```
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$loader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
$loader->suppressNotFoundWarnings(false);
```

Then when you try to load YourModel which resides in your models path, the autoloader should be able to handle it and you can build your references using the simple names.

Even though your application is small, it's always good to use those best practices.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of PHP added the `use` keyword (Probably 5.3 with the addition of namespaces), but I've kept the class names the typical long ones to account for the lack of namespaces in Zend Framework and used the `use` to make them shorter in my scripts.  It also means that if I need to move or rename the classes for any reason I only have to change the one `use` statement per file.

```
use Application_Model_Users_User as Model_User;
```